# Change angle of gradient chart bars in xlxswriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Hi how do I change the angle of the angle in the bars - is there an option like 'angle' : 90?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the chart gradient fill angle in XlsxWriter like this:

```py
chart.add_series({
    'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6',
    'gradient': {'colors': ['#DDEBCF', '#9CB86E', '#156B13'],
                 'angle': 45}
})
```

See the [Chart formatting: Gradient Fill](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-formatting-gradient-fill) section of the XlsxWriter docs.